# compiz screen lock can be bypassed by `metacity --replace`, how to protect against it?

Tags: 14.04, security

While compiz is running, open a terminal and type:
`sleep 10;metacity --replace`
now lock your screen and wait, you will see compiz end and metacity comes in, in an unlocked state.
**What I expected was that compiz would not allow anything like that to happen, while it is locked. (and if it crashes while locked, it should take X together with it, and so all running applications)**

In the other hand, if you lock your screen using XScreenSaver, metacity will still replace compiz, but screen will remain locked (but have its flaws too, see the comments)!

It seems the compiz screen lock runs under compiz (dependent on it) while XScreenSaver is another independent process/instance; did I just bumped into a security problem?

Obs.: Compiz version: 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150122-0ubuntu1

PS.: I have metacity, and also jwm as when using some 3D applications, these work better when compiz is not running (here at least).

Comment: if you already have terminal access, you can just type startx and have a whole other session to work with

Comment: or, use htop to kill xsceensaver, basically, if someone gains access to the terminal, they have full access.

Comment: @mchid if I run a 3D application on the new X session, it has a good chance of intefering with the video memory that is being used by compiz (I guess that by the many glitches and artifacts I see). Some times, when returning to compiz virtual terminal, unity simply crashes and all opened windows are gone (not just compiz, the X and all windows are gone), and unity restarts on the login screen.

Comment: @mchid I actually meant xscreensaver did a good job by not letting the pc unlocked :)

Comment: what I am trying to say is that you should be able to bypass xscreensaver by using startx so it's not all that more secure

Comment: @mchid I mean how to prevent a locked screen to be taken away; how to ensure it will remain locked even if something like `metacity --replace` happens;

Comment: @mchid oh I see, so basically, xscreensaver also have its flaws..

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if someone has access to the user's terminal, there is no level of security.

For example, a user could use `htop` to kill `xscreensaver`.

Also, if a user gains access to the terminal, they should need a password.

The fix is to use a strong password and sign out of tty whenever you are done.

Comment: instead of simply locking, logouting could work if I hadnt works on-going like a compilation or some download, or some applications that take too long to open even on a ssd card, would be troubling to re-open everything; if suspend/resume at least worked properly (I dont even try after I tested it and went all wrong here, PC Desktop); I still wonder how these windowmanager replacing works, they just kill the other wm or ask it nicely to end? if it is asked, then compiz could just say NO in case screen is locked.

Comment: @AquariusPower screen locking is not the problem because they won't be able to do anything with no access to the command line.

Comment: @AquariusPower maybe you should start using `tmux` or `screen` and then logout.